# OpenCart: how to get product's manufacturer_id in shipping_method

Tags: php, opencart

I am new to Opencart, so please help.

I edited `product/product.php` controller and managed to pass `manufacturer_id` to `product/product.tpl`.

Now I am stuck on `quickcheckout/checkout`. I need to know how to fetch product's `manufacturer_id` and pass it to `shipping_method` (view or controller, but I would prefer controller) inside `quickcheckout/checkout`.

Thank you

Comment: your question is unclear, why do you throw many `x/y` things without determining type (controller function, view, model ...) + if you have already done it with `product/product.php` then you can just do it in the same way here!!

Comment: @AbdoAdel You're right, I was completely new to Opencart at that time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I ended up doing it (I know it's not optimal, but it works).

In *\system\library\cart.php*, at line 45, after `$product_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM...` I added:

```
    $GLOBALS['cart_manufacturer_id'] = $product_query->row['manufacturer_id'];
```

I fetch that in *\catalog\view\theme\eagency\template\quickcheckout\checkout.tpl* using a global previously defined in cart.php, and finally, send it to *\catalog\controller\quickcheckout* as a URI param (I am using AJAX), thus:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=quickcheckout/shipping_method&ncal_cart_manufacturer_id=<?php echo $GLOBALS['cart_manufacturer_id']; ?>'
```

I know this is far of optimal, but since I didn't have time to learn Opencart, I just came up with something that worked.

In any case, I hope I'll help someone.